# Nokogiri XML builder adding unwanted "class='call'" to my XML?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have to send a test request to an API to get verified:

```
def fake_xml
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.TrackRequest.('USERID' => USPS_API["user_id"]) {
      xml.TrackID('ID' => 'EJ958083578US')
    }
  end
  puts builder.to_xml
  return builder.to_xml
end
```

However, this produces:

```
<TrackRequest class="call" USERID="xxxx">
  <TrackID ID="EJ958083578US"/>
</TrackRequest>
```

I don't want `class="call"` because it's messing up the request and causing it to return a failed response. How do I remove it or stop Nokogiri from automatically adding that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.TrackRequest('USERID' => '12') {
      xml.TrackID('ID' => 'EJ958083578US')
    }
end

puts builder.to_xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <TrackRequest USERID="12">
# >>   <TrackID ID="EJ958083578US"/>
# >> </TrackRequest>
```

No `.` should be here `xml.TrackRequest.('USERID' => USPS_API["user_id"])`. Just plain `xml.TrackRequest('USERID' => USPS_API["user_id"])`.